# how to add domain name in cookies using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I want to add some value with domain name in cookies using JQuery (1.6.1)and jquery.cookie.js plug-in. I am able to add Value in cookies with below code.

```
  $.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', { expires : 10 });
```

But I am not able to add the data in cookies with below code.Even unable to add cookie name or value to browser.

Code

```
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', { expires: 10, domain: 'example.com', secure: true })
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/tWWm4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following links:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

It may helps you.

Comment: I have checked it, First Link did not talk about domain. Second one is not working form me. I am not accessing the page as web application. I am opening this page as file in browser Like "file:///D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/srikanth.chilukuri/Desktop/jquery/index.html"